# Signing in Inno Setup fails with "Sign Tool failed with exit code 0x1"

Tags: window, windows-installer, installation, inno-setup, installshield

I have Inno Setup script, where I need to use the `SignTool=signtool`, which is configured properly and worked in past.

[image]

But it's failing when I try to compile with the following error:

> Sign Tool failed with exit code 0x1.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to run Sign command directly via command line to see if it also fails? You'd see proper error message then. 
Are you able to compile your installer without Signing? I have encountered simillar issue once where Windows blocked access to installer's temporary files because it treated `Compil32.exe` as untrusted process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't provide us any information that we can use to debug your problem.

So I'm posting generic instructions to debug issues with a "sign tool".

1. Try [command-line compiler (`ISCC.exe`)](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline). It will preserve a full `signtool.exe` error message in the output:

   [image]

2. Or temporarily prefix the sign tool command with `cmd.exe /k` to preserve its output even when compiling in Inno Setup GUI Compiler. E.g.:

   ```
   cmd.exe /k C:\path\to\signtool.exe sign /f C:\mykey.pfx $f
   ```

   [image]

   Note that if you use a path to `signtool.exe` with spaces, due to the way `cmd` works, you have to wrap not only the path itself to double quotes, but also the whole command:

   ```
   cmd.exe /k ""C:\path to signtool\signtool.exe" sign /f C:\mykey.pfx $f"
   ```

---

See also [signtool fail with Inno Setup with exit code 0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30863018/850848#30867119).

Answer (score 0):

When using an EV with a token,  you can assign the fingerprint using `/a /sha1 [Hash]`.

like so:

```
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /sha1 certfingerprint $f
```

This will make signtool to choose the cert from token.

More info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe