# Powershell signcode.exe Innosetup

Tags: inno-setup

EDITED:

I have problems with InnoSetup and signtool. The following works perfectly from the Command Line (I reverted from PowerShell in my original post to CMD).

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f certificate.p12 /p password /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll MyApp.exe
```

However, if I put the same line in InnoSetup IDE (adding $f at the end as requested by InnoSetup), it fails with "sign tool failed with exit code 0x1". I have already seen the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685417/inno-setup-signing-fails-with-sign-tool-failed-with-exit-code-0x1), however as on the command line it works fine, it doesn't help.
Without the codetool line "SignTool=signtool", InnoSetup compiles correctly.

Comment: *"My suspect is that on Windows 10 InnoSetup needs the same systax as in PowerShell."* - That's a very wrong assumption. - This is [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/218578).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell, use the `&` symbol (aka *call operator* or *invocation operator*) to execute a command name that contains quotes and whitespace.

```
& "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86\signtool.exe" sign /f certificate.p12 /p password /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll MyApp.exe
```

Why? Because PowerShell interprets a quoted string (first on the line) as a string, rather than a command. The `&` operator means "the string that follows is a command."

Read the PowerShell help topic `about_Operators` for more information.

Comment: It did not work even with &, PowerShell complained & is a wrong syntax. Anyway, I turned to the normal Command Line.

Comment: The command I posted is for use at the PowerShell command line. If it doesn't work (and I would point out that [you did not say _how_ it didn't work](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100421-00/?p=14283/)), then you are not doing it correctly (I do this all the time and it works just fine).