# Can I sign the Inno Setup installer after it is compiled instead of using SignTool directive?

Tags: inno-setup, code-signing, signtool

I've had a lot of trouble getting Inno Setup's `SignTool` feature to work on our Windows install.

I'm thinking now of doing the code signing myself outside of Inno Setup.

If I manually code sign our exe before using Inno Setup to build the installer, and then manually code sign the resulting `Setup.exe`, does that give the same degree of code signing that using `SignTool` does?

Does `SignTool` sign the `Setup.exe` as well as whatever `.exe` we specify on the signtool screen?

Does `SignTool` also sign *other* internal `.exe`'s that Inno Setup perhaps produces? (I ask this because I recall from years ago that there's a `filename.tmp` exe that gets run by the `Setup.exe`.  Does `SignTool` do anything to that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that the very reason Inno Setup has the [`SignTool` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) at all is the fact, that you cannot completely code sign the installer externally.

The reason being that there are indeed two internal executable files generated during compilation:

- an internal installer (the .tmp that you refer to), and
- an uninstaller

That is in addition to signing:

- the installer itself (which you can indeed sign yourself after the installer is compiled) and
- optionally any included binaries, if they have the [`sign` or `signonce` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=sign) (those you can indeed sign yourself before compiling the installer).

---

*So maybe you should actually ask a new question about your problem with `SignTool` directive. It's not really difficult to set up.*

See also these questions to learn, how to debug problems with `SignTool`:

- [Signing in Inno Setup fails with "Sign Tool failed with exit code 0x1"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39685417/850848)
- [signtool fail with Inno Setup with exit code 0x1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30863018/850848#30867119)