# InnoSetup - fails to use global sign EV code signing

Tags: windows, windows-installer, inno-setup, installshield, code-signing

In past i had other code signing which worked with innoSetup. But recently i purchased EV code signing for three year which is USB token certificate.

when i do manually without InnoSetup it works.

[image]

how do i do it with innosetup?

I tried following but it always failed.

```
[Setup]
...
SignTool=signtool
```

[image]

**EDIT:** dialogin window keep asking press ok or cancel, when i click ok it keeps repeating.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I never use Inno-setup, but what is up with the double, prepended braces for the AppId GUID? It says: `AppId={{5108BBF0-3BE0-44E4-977A-82A871794693}`. Could this cause the setup.exe to fail to compile so there is nothing to sign? [**Maybe also check this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863018/signtool-fail-with-inno-setup-with-exit-code-0x1).

Comment: And just [a direct link to a specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39685417/inno-setup-signing-fails-with-sign-tool-failed-with-exit-code-0x1/39689799#39689799) on how to preserve a full signtool.exe error message in the output.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul `{{` is required because `{` is special. You need to double it up.

Comment: See above EDIT. BUG when pressing OK or CANCEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not specifying the correct location for the signtool.exe.  When you run it manually, it is in `c:\Users\tpt\Desktop\\github\CERTIFICATE\certificate\software`.  In your InnoSetup, you're pointing to `c:\Users\tpt\Desktop\innosetup\software`.  You need to change the signtools setting in InnoSetup to point to the correct location.

Comment: NOT WORKING - see above my EDIT. InnoSetup is in dead lock shows that popup and when i click OK it keeps showing that popup.? is it a BUG?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the unsigned setup directory just replace it with $f